# Formulários longos

Tags: formulário, usabilidade

Já entendo que a melhor prática é usar um campo por linha, a não ser que ele tenha uma relação direta, como por exemplo:
Endereço e número. [Referência.](https://medium.com/@allanroubertie/12-dicas-de-ux-para-criar-formul%C3%A1rios-eficientes-6fc621a3ea05)

Porém trabalho em um sistema que em muitos campos, eles podem ser obrigatórios ou não dependendo da empresa que a utiliza, isso será customizável.

Uma resistência interna é geralmente reclamar de se usar esse modelo, o formulário fica muito longo, precisando dar scroll, e colocando vários campos um o lado do outro, prejudica a leitura e fica com cara de sistema delphi antigo, e uns aplicativos que usam aqui internamente tem essa cara, ou seja, para a empresa são exemplo de interfaces boas, o que eu não concordo.

Numa tela de consulta, isso também seria ruim, pois a tela de consulta, geralmente é a mesma tela de cadastro, com os input preenchidos, podendo assim o usuário editar informações (pra esse caso estou pensando em alterar a aparência da tela de consulta para algo menos cara de formulário.

Estou pesquisando sobre mas não tenho achado nada. Alguém tem referências de sistemas que usem muitos campos, mas que consiga usar essas boas praticas?

PS: já pensei também sobre telas step-to-step, mas também existe essa resistência.

Comment: "Melhores práticas" deixam de ser "melhores" quando não resolve o seu problema - e você nunca é obrigado a seguí-las. Um desconhecido na internet fala que precisa fazer X, mas seu usuário quer Y. Quem você atenderá? Para mim é um tanto quanto óbvio que seria Y. Aliás, se há tanta resistência assim, não entendi bem qual o intuito da pergunta. Seus usuários parecem ter um gosto muito bem definido, mas espera que outros desconhecidos digam o contrário?

Comment: a resistência não são dos usuários, e sim da equipe de desenvolvimento. Eu apenas contextualizei a situação para poder pedir as referencias e pq as quero.

Comment: Discordo de quase tudo o que está escrito na referência, mesmo que eu concorde por padrão, discordo porque depende do cenário. Geralmente o *scroll* é terrível, e mesmo que as outras coisas sejam problemáticas, e não estou dizendo que é, elas são pequenas perto do *scroll* ou uso de *tabs*. Mas depende de cada caso. A referência é só a opinião da pessoa sem nenhuma base concreta. Não sei nem se serve para a pessoa que escreveu. Se o cliente entende que algo é bom, provavelmente (nem sempre, mas costuma ser). Isto é usabilidade, não é o que o programador acha.O programador segue o cliente ou...

Comment: ...**prova** que o jeito dele é melhor, mesmo que seja fazendo dos 2 jeitos e colocando para o cliente testar (quem sabe fazendo um A/B). Quase todos sistemas são ruins em UX, as pessoas não ligam pra isso e fazem como bem entendem.

Comment: Existem muitos formulários com múltiplas colunas de campos que são extremamente usuais. Veja um [exemplo](https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/931813/screenshots/3358549/forms.png) | [exemplo](https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/78806/screenshots/2272774/attachments/426949/dribbble_preview_real_pixels.jpg). Basta saber trabalhar com a necessidade do usuário e dados a serem exibidos. "Melhores práticas" jamais deve der regra de desenvolvimento.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss não achei esses exemplos muito bons :) Especialmente o segundo. Tem muitas questões que fazer o form ser + amigável, estar tudo em uma coluna ganha-se muito pouco e costuma perder muito, mas se não associar bem os campos nas linhas de forma coerente fica pior, então é complicado, não é uma decisão entre x e y, é sobre todas colunas possível do Excel :)

Comment: o exemplo que o Anderson deu é bom, ele continua mantendo o formulário em uma única coluna, como blocos laterais. Quando me referi a multiplas colunas, me referia a outra situação, onde o campos fica lado a lado, tipo esse [formulário](https://www.vivaolinux.com.br/imagens/artigos/comunidade/Tela%20cadastro%20Suf%20Lazarus.jpg) daqui pra pior

Comment: a questão da coluna única é facilitar a leitura, no exemplo, vc passa pela coluna A, e depois pela coluna B. Ainda não vejo como a melhor forma, mas já fica muito melhor que socar vários inputs um do lado do outro.